# Generating a long string in AutoFixture

Tags: c#, autofixture

I want to generate a random string of - say length 80.

I'm thinking something like `Fixture.Create<string>(length: 80);`
or `Fixture.Create<string>(minimumLength: 60, maximumLenth: 100);`. Both would work perfectly fine.

Creating a Customization *seems* overkill, but maybe that's the correct approach. There are plenty of questions regarding getting a *shorter* string than the default, which can be achieved with substring, but I need a longer one.

Comment: Have you considered asking AutoFixture for more than one string, and then concatenate them together until it has the length you desire?

Comment: Also: why do you need this?

Comment: Yes I did consider that but thought the intention would be cleaner if I could specify it directly in the API. The reason I want a long string is to assert that my model validation works properly, for example that my `RangeAttribute` kicks in as expected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
string.Join(string.Empty,Fixture.CreateMany<char>(stringLength))
```

`stringLength` is how long you wanted your generated string to be.

or

By default `Fixture.Create<string>()` creates a string of length 36.
So if you want a string length more than 36, this code will generate a string of length 72:

```
string.Join(string.Empty,Fixture.CreateMany<string>(2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125199/autofixture-configure-fixture-to-limit-string-generation-length) question.

This says that `StringLength` attribute can help generate strings of a given length.

Also there is an [article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/11/07/Creatinglength-constrainedstringswithAutoFixture/) from a library maintainer. In this article he says that the method like eq `fixture.Build<MyObject>.With(x = x.MyString, 0, 100);` will not be implemented by design considerations.

So if you don't want to use the attribute than you have to run with `Customization`

Comment: Well that question uses `CreateAnonymous` (which is deprecated) and talks about shortening only. I don't see how it helps me?

Comment: The article says that the method for just making a string will not be created because of the design considerations. Although the article is written in 2012 the fact that there is no such method may say that you will need to use another approach (like you've already said). Also I didn't get the point about longer string: do you need a string of random characters or random length in given range?

Comment: Random length in a given range, or just a specific length

Comment: May the `StringLength` attribute help? It is not clear from [this](http://blog.nikosbaxevanis.com/2011/09/18/stringlengthattribute-support-in-autofixture/) announcement will it add new chars to a string but it may help.

Comment: Maybe - seems you must decorate your non-test code with this attribute to work, and I prefer not to clutter the code with test-related stuff

Comment: I see. So in that case if somebody will not provide a better advice than it seems that you should have to create Customization.

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight-forward way to accomplish this, as already [pointed out by Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980948/2874896).

**The closest I could get was to use** `Fixture.CreateMany<string>(3).Join("")`. Thanks to Mark Seemann for the tip.

I just wanted a string more than 50 characters, but didn't care if it was 100 or 300. If I however wanted a precise length I could also call `Fixture.CreateMany<string>(3).Join("").Substring(length)`

Comment: Looks like this issue could be addresses by this AutoFixture improvement: https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/678. Unfortunately it requires .NET 4.5 so it cannot be accomplished in AF 3.x based on .NET 4.0

Answer (score 0):

```cs
    private Func<int, string> LongStringFactory { get; }

    public TodoTaskControllerTest()
    {
        LongStringFactory = (len) => string.Join("", Fixture.CreateMany<char>(len).ToArray());
    }

    [Fact]
    private async Task CreateTodoFailWhenTitleCraterMoreThan250Characters()
    {
        CreateOrUpdateTodoTaskDto request = Fixture.Build<CreateOrUpdateTodoTaskDto>()
            .With(x => x.Title, LongStringFactory(251))
          .Create();
```